# Logging system calls of external Process created by Java with Seccomp

Tags: java, kubernetes, system-calls, processbuilder, seccomp

I would like to log all system calls made by a Java application and the processes started from the application with a Seccomp profile. Im running the applcation within a Kubernetes pod and supplying the seccomp profile through the yml.

Is there a way to log **all** system calls by the application and processes created by it?

Currently, I am using Java's Processbuilder for the external process. If I create a file through an external process from ProcessBuilder (let's say the external process does 'echo hello > message') I would expect the syslogs to contain something like system call "1" for writing to a file.
However, no syscall for writing to a file shows in the logs (even though the file was created)
This is my seccomp profile:

```
{
    "defaultAction": "SCMP_ACT_LOG"
}
```